# OpenCV compliation on linux: how to feed to it specific zlib lib?

Tags: opencv, static, compilation, static-libraries, zlib

I want to compile OpenCV with same zlib as I use for compilation of Boost Iostreams (not system default one). I want to compile OpenCV as static lib, having zlib compiled as static lib.  Currently I use something like :

```
 ../$CMAKE_PATH -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./$OPENCV_INSTALL_SUBDIR -DBUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=OFF -DOPENCV_EXTRA_C_FLAGS=-fPIC -DOPENCV_BUILD_3RDPARTY_LIBS=TRUE
make
make install
echo Done!
```

I wonder: having some `$ZLIB_HEADERS` and `$ZLIB_LIB_FILES_FOLDER` path strings how to feed them into cmake to get OpenCV compiled with built by me zlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try cmake-gui or ccmake. Make sure to toggle advanced mode On (press t in ccmake).
You will find ZLIB_LIBRARY and ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR.

Comment: I know but 1) I do not see such option for OpenCV in there, 2) There are lots of times GUI is not an option (server machines). And it is not an option for me.

Comment: @myWallJSON Well, then you can use ccmake instead. Updated