# Error Importing OpenCV Framework to Unity Project iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, compiler-errors, unity-game-engine, linker-errors

I built OpenCV using the script available here:
http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/

Then created a Unity3d iOS project, generated the xcode project from Unity3d, added the OpenCV framework to the project and tried to compile.

I get the following error:

```
duplicate symbol _adler32 in /my-path/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(adler32.o) and /my-path/OpenCV.framework/OpenCV(adler32.o) for architecture armv7
```

I tried to remove adler32.so from the OpenCV lib, using "lipo" and "ar" then repackaged the lib, and I got another duplicated symbol. Eventually I removed a lot of objects from the OpenCV lib and it started complaining about missing symbols.

It was a fun experiment but didn't work.

If I create a project on xcode with OpenCV it compiles without errors.
Unity3d project without OpenCV also works.

- xcode version: 4.3.3
- unity3d version: 3.5.2 (latest)
- OpenCV: 2.4.1 - Adding OpenCV as a framework.

I searched for a linker option under xcode to see if I could make it more permissive but didn't found anything.

Any idea how to solve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like both Unity and OpenCV are being built with their own copies of `libz`, and are conflicting at link time.  (`_adler32` is a checksumming function used in this library.)

You will need to pick one framework to own these common libraries and rebuild accordingly.  Since `libz` is in iOS anyway, you might as well build both frameworks to use the system versions of those libraries.

Comment: I can't control the Unity lib so thats out of option. What I can do, and did like stated above, was to remove it from the OpenCV Framework. When doing that I found more and more "shared" symbols which I removed from OpenCV, eventually some of those object files contained diferences and if I removed those objects OpenCV would start complaining about missing symbols. I'm not completely sure why it happens. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I don't think just using `lipo` and `ar` is sufficient to solve this. You really need to rebuild OpenCV while specifying `ZLIB_LIBRARY` and `ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR` to correctly resolve all linker references.

Comment: Are you able to provide some guidance on how and with what values to define ZLIB_LIBRARY and ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR? I'm a bit lost on the process of building OpenCV

Comment: I just found a SO question that specifically addresses that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236028/opencv-compliation-on-linux-how-to-feed-to-it-specific-zlib-lib

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. Sorry for the delay in accepting the answer I was busy with other parts of the project and just came back to this today.